# Finding a Path Recursively, Overflow?

Tags: java, recursion, path

I've been working on my Lab Assignment for my CS class, 
I have to fill in a method supplied to me by the Instructor, 
I've gotten to a point where I can navigate to a point in the array and 
mark the direction to move in, but It only works for some positions even
though I can see a clear path.

for example if I enter 8,2 It finds the path just fine

Here's a pic:

[image]

but If I enter the point 8,3 which is clearly passable  I get 
an Overflow and my program just jumps back and forth between line 24 and 35

If anyone has any ideas of where I am going wrong, I would appreciate some tips! 
Thanks Everyone

```
public char[][] findPath(int startRow, int startCol, int destRow, int destCol,  int threshold){

    if((startRow==destRow)&&(startCol==destCol)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A path has been found!");
        map[destRow][destCol] = '^';

        return map;

        }

    else if(startRow < 9 && checkIfPassable(startRow + 1, startCol, threshold)){
        map[startRow][startCol]= 'S';
        startRow++;
        return findPath( startRow,  startCol, destRow, destCol, threshold);

        }
    else if(startCol < 9 && checkIfPassable(startRow , startCol + 1, threshold)){
        map[startRow][startCol]= 'E';
        startCol++;
        return findPath( startRow,  startCol, destRow, destCol, threshold);
     }
    else if(startRow > 1 && checkIfPassable(startRow -1, startCol, threshold)){
        map[startRow][startCol]= 'S';
        startRow--;
        return findPath( startRow,  startCol, destRow, destCol, threshold);

        }
    else if(startCol > 1 && checkIfPassable(startRow , startCol -1, threshold)){
        map[startRow][startCol]= 'E';
        startCol--;
        return findPath( startRow,  startCol, destRow, destCol, threshold);
     }



    System.exit(1);
    return map;

}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You should attempt to debug this yourself:

- Run the program with an attached debugger.  (Since you are using Eclipse, this is very easy to do.  Ditto for other IDEs.  Otherwise, check the Oracle documentation on `jdb` - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/jdb.html)
- Set a breakpoint to stop the program at the appropriate place.
- Single step the program as it recurses, examining the state of the local variables and the relevant `map` cells.
- Identify how it is behaving differently to what you expect.
- Modify your algorithm.

---

Now we could attempt to figure our what is going wrong for you, but you've not shown us enough of the code.  And more importantly, *you need to learn to do this yourself!*

Comment: Thank you I got a little bit further I added checks to see if I've already been a specific location. The program now finds most of the locations

Answer (score 0):

Your search algorithm needs to be more systematic. As this is written, you'll just go around in circles until you overflow the stack. You need to make sure you don't backtrack over spaces you have already visited.

On a stylistic note, if you are going with a recursive implementation, you should make all the method parameters `final` and just use `+1` or `-1` where you make the recursive calls, rather than using `++` or `--` before the recursive calls, so that it is clear just by liking at the recursive calls which way the recursion is going. Also, opening dialog boxes or killing the application inside a computation is generally bad form. Use `System.out.println` or a logging library if you want feedback about what your code is doing.